# Question about SetSocketOption & MulticastOption

Tags: c#, sockets, multicast

I create a group & send a message 1 line before the method `Receive` wait for a message by creating a thread. This code works *Perfectly*. I just want to know why shouldn't I add this line in the `Send` method too for joining the socket to the group before I try send something to the group.

`server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, MulticastOption);`

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

class MAIN
{
    private static MulticastOption CreateGroup()
    {
        return new MulticastOption(IPAddress.Parse("224.100.0.1"));
    }
    private static void Receive(MulticastOption MulticastOption)
    {
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
        EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;
        sock.Bind(iep);
        sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, MulticastOption);
        //
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(Send)).Start();
        int recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
        String stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
        Console.WriteLine("received: {0} from: {1}", stringData, ep.ToString());
        sock.Close();
    }
    private static void Send()
    {
        Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("224.100.0.1"), 9050);


        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test message");
        server.SendTo(data, iep);
        server.Close();
    }
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Receive(CreateGroup());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.sockets.com/ch16.htm#Multicast):

> The IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP option allows
>   you to join a multicast group
>   specified by the host group address in
>   the multicast address structure. You
>   must join a group to receive multicast
>   datagrams. ***You do not need to join a
>   group to send multicast datagrams.***

However, this will only work on the local subnet due to the default TTL value.  See [this article](http://codeidol.com/csharp/csharp-network/IP-Multicasting/Csharp-IP-Multicast-Support/) for a more explicit answer.